# iterating cursor mongodb + php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

Can someone tell me how to iterate over `$cursor` for my mongodb/php search below? I want to print all results from column '`query`' where `result != "-"`.

```
$filter = array("query" => array('$ne' => "-"));
$cursor = $collection->find($filter);
echo $cursor->count() . ' document(s) found. ';</pre></code>
```

I have tried:

```
foreach ($cursor as $obj) {
array_push ($dnsArray, $obj['query']);
}
```

The result being - 
'266597 document(s) found.' ...
but when I loop through $dnsArray:

```
foreach($dnsArray as $query){
echo "$query";
}
```

There are no results.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong.. Are you sure you have data in "query" field?

Comment: Yeah there is definitely data... but I just tried $ne on another column and it worked... maybe there is an indexing issue in "query"... i'll try find out. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `$obj['query']` ? Shouldn't it just be `$obj`?

Comment: To debug your retreive data you should use var_dump(iterator_to_array($cursor));
Then you see the entire result set and you can take it from there.